# python: convert list of strings of json type to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I have file where each line is json string. I load this file to a list of strings. Is there way to convert all this strings to a list of dictionaries?   `json.loads()` can convert only line by line. thanks

---

I figure out one way of doing it: `L = list(expression for variable in sequence)`

Comment: What's wrong with using map( json.loads, my_list) ?

Comment: that works. I am new to python. I love it =)

Comment: by the way what is effective way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
result = None
with open("filename", 'r') as fh:
    result = [json.loads(line) for line in fh]
```

Or you can use `map` instead of list comprehensions as @JeffS said

```
result = None
with open("filename", 'r') as fh:
    result = map(json.loads, fh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the json module for loading [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html). (Pre-2.6 use the third party simplejson module, which has the same exact API.)

```
>>> import json
>>> f = open(‘json.file’,'r’)
>>> d = json.loads(f.read())
>>> print d
```

or use the old hack using the similarity between json and python dict syntax, **but only use this hack if you are sure that json file does not contain json comment ..**

```
f = open('json.file','r')
d = eval(f.read())
```